# Google Analytics Content Experiment Tracking Code

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

i'm setting up my first content experiment, and having a single confussion, i tried to search for reference but couldn't find it.

I would like to know if the Content Experiment Code should replace only in single file ? or it Smart Enough to detect which page that need to execute the test ?

Because i'm using wordpress, i can directly place it to header.php under after the opening head tag, but if it only for a single page, i might have to run some if..else statement

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to add the content-experiment code snippet to the particular page you want to experiment with, and not the entire website.

[From here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745152?hl=en&ref_topic=1745207),

> Adding script code to your page
>
> 1. Make sure your original and variation pages have Google Analytics tracking code installed.
> 2. Then, paste this experiment code immediately after the opening head tag at the top of **your original page**.